# np.where() or another boolean way for new pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to create a column in a dataframe with stock prices that is conditional on the boolean values from another calculation.

```
              close    high   low
    Index
      0        10       11     10
      1        11       12     10
      2        10       11      9
```

First I want to define some condition(s) that could logically look like that but in fact are a lengthy :

```
 condition1: if df.close > df.close.shift() return True
```

In real I want to define many more conditions that all deliver True or False. Then I include that in the np.where():

```
 df['NewColumn'] = np.where(condition1() == True, 'A', 'B')
```

I tried to define the condition as a function but did not manage to correctly set it up. I would like to avoid to write the content of the condition directly into the np.where() because it would become too complex with several nested conditions.

So, how can I accomplish my task most efficiently?

Edit: a function could look like this (but it does not work in the np.where() above):

```
def condition1(): 
    if df.Close > df.Close.shift(1):
        return True
    Else
        return False
```

Comment: `numpy.where(df.close > df.close.shift(), 'A', 'B')` should work

Comment: Care to share ***the condition you tried to define as a function but did not manage to correctly set it up***?

Comment: @Paul H, I want to avoid writing the condition directly into the formula due to the complexity and number of the real conditions

Comment: @Abdou I added an example how I imagined to set it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** IMO you don't need "conditions" as functions:

```
In [89]: cond1 = df.Close > df.Close.shift(1)

In [90]: cond2 = df.High < 12

In [91]: df['New_Close'] = np.where(cond1, 'A', 'B')

In [92]: df
Out[92]:
   Close  High  Low New_Close
0     10    11   10         B
1     11    12   10         A
2     10    11    9         B

In [93]: df['New_High'] = np.where(cond1, '<12', '>=12')

In [94]: df
Out[94]:
   Close  High  Low New_Close New_High
0     10    11   10         B     >=12
1     11    12   10         A      <12
2     10    11    9         B     >=12
```

**OLD answer:**

I don't really see any advantages (benefit) of this approach, but you can do it this way:

```
def condition1(): 
    return (df.Close > df.Close.shift(1))

def condition2(): 
    return (df.High < 12)


In [72]: df['New_Close'] = np.where(condition1(), 'A', 'B')

In [73]: df
Out[73]:
   Close  High  Low New_Close
0     10    11   10         B
1     11    12   10         A
2     10    11    9         B

In [74]: df['New_High'] = np.where(condition2(), '<12', '>=12')

In [75]: df
Out[75]:
   Close  High  Low New_Close New_High
0     10    11   10         B      <12
1     11    12   10         A     >=12
2     10    11    9         B      <12
```

PS IMO it would be easier and nicer to do it directly like [@PaulH said in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163892/np-where-or-another-boolean-way-for-new-pandas-dataframe-column/40164175#comment67596721_40163892)

Comment: thank you, this seems to work. The benefit is mostly optical in nature. Should improve the readability of the np.where() when it becomes long and nested.